# Exception is not received in the main Activiti from the inner Activiti

Tags: java, exception, activiti

We are using Activiti BPMN diagrams to run our workflows.
In our main process we're running additional process(innerProcess)
inside of a service task - MyServiceTask . See below.
The issue is that if there is an exception thrown in the innerProcess process, then I won't get it in MyServiceTask, only after the main process finished, then the exception will be bubbled up.

But I want to be able to catch the exception in MyServiceTask in case it happens.
Can you help?

```
public class MyServiceTask implements JavaDelegate
{

    @Inject
    private RuntimeService runtimeService;

    public void execute(DelegateExecution context) throws Exception
    {
          runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("innerProcess", paramMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you are not running a second "Activiti". Rather you are initiating a new process instance. All process instances are isolated and errors are associated with a specific instance. The only exception to that rule is when a process instance is a "sub process". In this case, errors can bubble up to the parent process instance.

I would modify your logic to start a sub process instance wither via a signal (probably the easiest way) or directly from within the service.

Sub process instances differ only in that they have a parent process instance id which can be set on initialization.

Comment: what do you mean by "start a sub process instance directly from within the service"? and I still don't understand why the exception is not bubbled up first time, only from the second and on.

Comment: Perhaps I didnt correctly understand what youwere saying about first iteration and second iteration. Either way, to initiate a sub process programatically from a java delegate you would use something like below:

public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
    ActivityExecution activityExecution = (ActivityExecution) execution;
    PvmProcessInstance subProcessInstance = activityExecution.createSubProcessInstance(processDefinition);

    // TODO set variables

    subProcessInstance.start();
}

Comment: is there a way to run the new process so it wan't be associated with the parent process, so it'll run as independent process in new transaction?